# Windows Phone Privacy policy default message when you install a location app?

Tags: windows-phone-7

I am building an app that uses the location service api.

However I am not sure if I have to implement the default Windows Phone Privacy policy message when you install an app? I have already done the permission functionality when a user starts using my app but I am not sure what to do with the installation message? Is it set by default when you set the category of your app via the submission wizard or not?

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft will detect what services your app uses and prompt the user that your app includes these and ask them to confirm that they want to allow the installation to continue. So there's nothing you need to do in that respect.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure in what extent you implemented your permission functionality within your app, but just to be sure: you need a Privacy Statement prompt on first launch, an option to turn off location services and a link to access the statement again.  I didn't read the guidelines properly, thus dooming the certification of my app.

Comment: As far as I know it is not possible to turn off location services pragmatically?

Comment: @KateBrown You can have a setting to not use location services inyour application, if your customer so desires.